# Escape single quote in html (Greasemonkey script)

Tags: html, escaping, greasemonkey, double-quotes, quote

I have this html code working on GreaseMonkey extension for webbrowsers:

```
document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace("value=\"9,00\"","value=\"4,00\"");
```

But what really I want is to match the full line:

```
<td><input name='nota3'  size='5' READONLY value="9,00" >
```

I've tried to escape the single quotes like the doublequotes in the first example but is not working:

```
document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace("<td><input name=\'nota3\'  size=\'5\' READONLY value=\"9,00\" >","<td><input name=\'nota3\'  size=\'5\' READONLY value=\"4,00\" >");
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace("<td><input name='nota3'  size='5' READONLY value=\"9,00\" >","<td><input name='nota3'  size='5' READONLY value=\"4,00\" >");
```

You don't need to escape the single quotes, because they're enclosed in double quotes, and therefore do not interfere with closing the double quotes.